# Groovy named and default arguments

Tags: groovy, arguments, argument-passing

Groovy supports both default, and named arguments. I just dont see them working together.

I need some classes to support construction using simple non named arguments, and using named arguments like below:

```
def a1 = new A(2)
def a2 = new A(a: 200, b: "non default")

class A extends SomeBase {
    def props
    A(a=1, b="str") { 
        _init(a, b)
    }

    A(args) { 
       // use the values in the args map:
       _init(args.a, args.b)
       props = args
    }

    private _init(a, b) {
    }

}
```

Is it generally good practice to support both at the same time?  Is the above code the only way to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The given code will cause some problems.  In particular, it'll generate two constructors with a single Object parameter.  The first constructor generates bytecode equivalent to:

```
A() // a,b both default
A(Object) // a set, b default
A(Object, Object) // pass in both
```

The second generates this:

```
A(Object) // accepts any object
```

You can get around this problem by adding some types.  Even though groovy has dynamic typing, the type declarations in methods and constructors still matter.  For example:

```
A(int a = 1, String b = "str") { ... }
A(Map args) { ... }
```

As for good practices, I'd simply use one of the [`groovy.transform.Canonical`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html) or [`groovy.transform.TupleConstructor`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) annotations.  They will provide correct property map and positional parameter constructors automatically.  TupleConstructor provides the constructors only, Canonical applies some other best practices with regards to `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Comment: Unfortunately your URLs are now dead, but they should be found here:

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html

Comment: Links fixed now. :)